# Как избавиться от ошибки import * only allowed at module level в Python?

Tags: python, opengl

Рисую сцену на OpenGL, где использую модули **OpenGL.GL** и **OpenGL.GLU**. Импортирую их в начале кода, не в функции:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

Однако получаю ошибку:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-8e7de8634b66>", line 2
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
                            ^
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
```

При этом в коде модуль используется лишь в строке `gluPerspective(45, width / float(height), 0.1, 50.0)`.

что вызывает ошибку и как избавиться?

Comment: Текст ошибки намекает, что вы импортируете их не в модуле, а в ipython

Comment: все верно - там и импортирую, в Jupyter Notebook. Однако иной раз в ячейке работает, а тут - не хочет

Comment: Попробуйте в Jupyter Notebook перезагрузить кернел.

Comment: @MarianD, пытался: все равно не пошло